# Problema al compilar plantillas en archivos separados en C++

Tags: c++, template

Obtengo este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando una plantilla en un archivo de encabezado y cuando compilo mis archivos sale ese error y no entiendo cual es mi falla.

clase.h

```
/*clase.h*/
#ifndef CLASE_H
#define CLASE_H

template <class V1>
class Escuela
{
    V1 nombre;
public:

    Escuela(V1 a);
    V1 getN() const;
    void SetN(V1 a); 
};

#endif //CLASE_H
```

El segundo archivo la definición de clase.h en clase.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "clase.h"
using namespace std;

template <class V1>
Escuela<V1>::Escuela(V1 a): nombre(a){}

template <class V1>
void Escuela<V1>::SetN(V1 a)
{
    this -> nombre = a;
}

template <class V1>
V1 Escuela<V1>::getN() const
{
    return nombre;
}
```

y el último archivo donde tengo el main mi archivo main.cpp

```
/*main.cpp*/
#include <iostream>
#include "clase.h"
using namespace std;

template <class V1>
ostream &operator << (ostream &o,const Escuela <V1> &rhs)
{
    o << rhs.getN();
    return o;
}

// typedef Escuela< string > clase;
// template class Escuela< string >;

int main()
{
    Escuela <string> S("Dr. Alfredo Pareja");

    cout << S;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Has dado con el error más habitual para los principiantes en el mundo de las plantillas de C++: has separado la declaración de la plantilla en un archivo de cabecera (`.h`) y la definición en un archivo de código (`.cpp`).

Para cualquier otro objeto no-plantilla de C++ esto habría sido válido, no es así para las plantillas<sup>1</sup>. La analogía perfecta para las plantillas de C++ es un [tampón (o sello) de tinta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamp%C3%B3n_de_tinta) configurable:

[image]

Siguiendo el ejemplo del sello de la imágen: hasta que no usas el tampón sobre el papel, la información no existe: podría representar cualquier fecha hasta 2026... pero no sabemos cuál.

En el momento que (tras impregnarlo de tinta) impactas el sello contra el papel la información existirá y representará una fecha concreta y específica.

#### Instanciar una plantilla.

Con las plantillas de C++ sucede igual, son un tampón de tinta que puede ser cualquier cosa, no es hasta el momento de instanciarlas que sabremos qué cosa son con exactitud.

La instancia de una plantilla es como configurar el tampón de tinta, seleccionando la fecha exacta a representar... pero en el caso de las plantillas se selecciona el tipo de dato a representar. Cuando se instancia, el parámetro de la plantilla se copia-reemplaza en todo el cuerpo:

```
template <class V1>
class Escuela
{
    V1 nombre;
public:

    Escuela(V1 a);
    V1 getN() const;
    void SetN(V1 a); 
};
```

Si instanciamos con `std::string` se substituirá `V1` por `std::string` resulntando esta clase:

```
class Escuela
{
    std::string nombre; // std::string reemplaza a V1
public:

    Escuela(std::string a); // std::string reemplaza a V1
    std::string getN() const; // std::string reemplaza a V1
    void SetN(std::string a); // std::string reemplaza a V1
};
```

Podemos ver que la clase resultante, carece de definición para todas sus funciones:

- No existe la definición de `Escuela::Escuela(std::string)`.
- No existe la definición de `std::string Escuela::getN()`.
- No existe la definición de `void Escuela::SetN(std::string)`.

Podríamos pensar que sí que existen, en el archivo de código (`.cpp`), pero nos equivocaríamos ya que en el archivo de código...

```
template <class V1>
Escuela<V1>::Escuela(V1 a): nombre(a){}

template <class V1>
void Escuela<V1>::SetN(V1 a)
{
    this -> nombre = a;
}

template <class V1>
V1 Escuela<V1>::getN() const
{
    return nombre;
}
```

¡En el archivo de código tenemos una plantilla! En este archivo no se ha hecho el buscar-reemplazar de `V1` por `std::string` así que las funciones requeridas carecen de definición.

#### Sugerencia.

Cuando uses plantillas, declara y define en el mismo archivo. Si esta opción no te gusta y prefieres seguir separando declaración y definición en diferentes archivos, renombra `clase.cpp` a `clase_def.h` e incluye el archivo de definición (`*_def.h`) al final del archivo de declaración:

```
/*clase.h*/
#ifndef CLASE_H
#define CLASE_H

template <class V1>
class Escuela
{
    V1 nombre;
public:

    Escuela(V1 a);
    V1 getN() const;
    void SetN(V1 a); 
};

#include "clase_def.h"

#endif //CLASE_H
```

---

<sup>1</sup>A no ser que se trate de especialización de plantillas, pero ese es otro tema que da para otra pegunta.

Answer (score 3):

Las plantillas son clases o funciones en las que al menos uno de los tipos implicados no está definido a la hora de indicar su interfaz:

```
// Qué tipo es T? int? float? una estructura?
template<class T> 
T func(T var);
```

Esta característica hace que una plantilla, tal cual está implementada, no sea compilable porque el compilador no tiene toda la información que necesita ¿Cuánto ocupa `T`? ¿Cabe en un registro o es necesario usar la pila? ¿Y si se trata de un puntero?

Es por esto que el compilador al encontrarse un template no hace absolutamente nada con el y espera a encontrarse usos del mismo para saber qué versiones del template debe compilar:

```
template<class T>
void func(T var)
{ std::cout << var << '\n'; }

int main()
{
  func(4);      // Se crea la versión func<int>
  func(1.2);    // Se crea la versión func<double>
  func("abcd"); // Se crea la versión func<const char*>
  func(1);      // La versión func<int> ya existe... no se generan nuevas versiones
}
```

Como vemos el proceso de compilación es diferente al habitual. Debido a que el compilador genera las especializaciones de las plantillas en el mismo momento en el que se van encontrando los usos, el compilador necesita conocer en todo momento tanto la declaración como la implementación de las plantillas. Si en una plantilla separas la declaración y la implementación en dos ficheros diferentes debes preparar el código para que ambos ficheros sean incluídos allí donde se use la plantilla:

template.h

```
#ifndef __TEMPLATE
#define __TEMPLATE

template<class T>
void func(T var);

// Se carga la implementación (en el caso de plantillas es necesaria)
#include "template.cpp"

#endif // __TEMPLATE
```

template.cpp

```
// este include ya no es necesario
// aunque se puede dejar para evitar errores de compilación
// si intentamos compilar por error este fichero.
#include "template.h"

#include <iostream>

template<class T>
T func(T var)
{ std::cout << var; }
```

Como vemos el proceso es diferente al resto de clases y funciones y puede resultar un poco más engorroso. Por este motivo lo más normal es encontrarse la plantilla declarada e implementada en un único fichero:

```
#ifndef __TEMPLATE
#define __TEMPLATE

#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void func(T var);

template<class T>
T func(T var)
{ std::cout << var; }

#endif // __TEMPLATE
```

Comment: ¡¡Pusiste `¿` en código fuente!! ¡¡horror!! :O (guiño, guiño).

Comment: Yo no soy inglés, y algunos compiladores que he usado se... *enfadan* en estos casos ;P

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Ya los he borrado... pero por ser tu el que se ha quejado :)

Comment: En realidad se quejó gcc, versión jurásica xD

Answer (score 2):

Las funciones, métodos, campos y variables que dependen de parámetros de plantillas, tanto en su declaración como en su código, no se deben definir en el archivo .cpp, deben quedar definidos en el header (.h).

Este asunto no es baladí y es un coladero de bugs importante para la programación en este lenguaje por muchos motivos, pero te comento varios problemas típicos.

**Nota:** En adelante se distinguen las declaraciones (.h), que son como una guía para el compilador; y las definiciones (.cpp), que será el código fuente final compilado que se enlazará por/entre otros objetos para formar una aplicación (exe) o una librería (dll, lib, ...).

Debes comprender que C++ es un lenguaje de enlace estático en tiempo de compilación, es decir, todas las declaraciones de tipos se interpretan, se recrean y enlazan entre sí en tiempo de la compilación de la "imagen" ejecutable resultante, y no se puede modificar ni un solo bit para que cumpla su función correctamente. Las plantillas, y las definiciones de sus miembros (campos, métodos, subclases, etc.), son tipos genéricos que dependen de parámetros para que sean declarados y su definición sólo se compila cuando se hace referencia a ellas en el código. Como los archivos .cpp se compilan por separado como objetos independientes (aunque después se vinculen para localizar las referencias simbólicas declaradas en el header), la compilación de las definiciones genéricas de un archivo .cpp no definen a priori las declaraciones de tipos de otros archivos .cpp.

Por ejemplo en tu caso, el archivo de código fuente (.cpp) que contiene la plantilla `Escuela` dependiente del parámetro `V1` se compila antes e independientemente al objeto .cpp que contiene la función `main` sin haber encontrado ninguna declaración que permita recrear el código fuente, por tanto se omiten las definiciones y el *linker* no encontrará los símbolos que requiere el objeto .cpp de `main`.

¿Te imaginas que se tuvieran que compilar todos los diferentes comportamientos del código fuente de las definiciones de la plantilla `Escuela<V1>` y del resto de plantillas de todos los tipos que se incluyen en todas las librerías de C++, y relacionarlas entre sí mismas, por si en algún caso las necesitas? Es como un cerdo volador pero sin el como. Esto sólo es posible en lenguajes de enlace dinámico a través de metadatos de tipos como Java, C#, VB (.NET) y análogos.

Si incluyes en el archivo .cpp de `Escuela` una variable de tipo `Escuela<std:string>` (fuera de los métodos) o una directiva `using TipoEcuela = Escuela<std:string>;`, el tipo quedaría declarado, definido, compilado y accesible desde otros objetos .cpp, **pero no es recomendable en absoluto**. Cualquier cambio en las versiones de las librerías enlazadas e incluso en el sistema, provocaría un comportamiento incontrolado con un final catastrófico y, probablemente, con otro programador engordando las listas del paro.

### Hay varias soluciones

Lo más sencillo es definir en la misma declaración de la plantilla, conocido como *inline definition*:

```
/*clase.h*/
#ifndef CLASE_H
#define CLASE_H

template <class V1>
class Escuela
{
    V1 nombre;
public:

    Escuela(V1 a): nombre(a){};

    V1 getN() const
    {
        return nombre;
    };

    void SetN(V1 a)
    {
        this -> nombre = a;
    }; 

};

#endif //CLASE_H
```

También puedes incluir las definiciones tal y como lo harías en el .cpp a continuación de la declaración.

O bien puedes poner las definiciones en otro archivo que no sea .c, .cc, .cxx o .cpp e incluirlo en el .h que contiene la declaración.

Una técnica elegante para mantener la coherencia del estilo entre tipos genéricos y no genéricos (y mi preferencia) es crear un archivo **.tpp** con las definiciones e incluirlo tras la declaración de la plantilla en el `.h` emulando el estilo de los archivos de código fuente `.cpp`. Desde hace tiempo la mayoría de entornos de programación reconocen los archivos .tpp como archivos de declaraciones de C++ o headers.

Por el contrario, los métodos de clases que no sean dependientes de parámetros genéricos (plantillas) y no sean `inline` o `static` siempre se deben definir en los archivos .cpp para que la compilación no duplique sus definiciones en cada objeto .cpp que incluya una referencia. Las clases con herencia `virtual` y *callbacks* desde DLLs pueden generar más catástrofes y más desempleo.

Los métodos `inline`, también deben ser declarados y definidos en el .h para que su comportamiento sea el esperado, de lo contrario se considera una función como otra cualquiera y más problemas.

### ¿Por qué C y C++ es así y no es más flexible?

Porque todo esto permite que una aplicación cualquiera vuele como si estuviese programada en lenguaje máquina o ensamblador, pero con un lenguaje comprensible para las personas y con una mínima preocupación por la optimización de los procesos, los procesadores, de la memoria y de las cientos de características entre diferentes plataformas, procesadores, placas, chips, PCs, móviles, etc.

Comment: Excelente explicación. Tal vez *demasiados* conceptos concentrados (vas a liar mas todavía al autor de la pregunta xD). Tuve que *releer* un par de veces lo de `static` para seguirte. Como dije, excelente. Un placer leer este tipo de respuestas.

Comment: En el último apartado yo eliminaría la referencia a `C`... `C` no dispone de plantillas ni de ningún tipo de flexibilidad al respecto.

Comment: Gracias @Trauma. Ahora que lo releo creo que me he enredado un poco, sí xD pero son conceptos básicos que hay que saber para programar en c++ cómodamente sin que termine en desastre

Comment: @eferion, C dispone de `inline` y `static` de los hago referencia, y el modelo de compilación, que es lo que pretendía explicar, es el padre de c++, ya te digo si se parecen. Por lo demás, la solución está en el primer párrafo y no hay que leer mucho más si no le interesa.

Comment: Yo es que difiero con respecto a tus opiniones. Si C o C++ son tan rígidos es mayormente porque son lenguajes que ya rondan los  40 - 50 años. Se podría conseguir la misma eficiencia con una sintaxis más agradable y una flexibilidad mayor pero eso implicaría prácticamente crear un lenguaje nuevo y dudo que eso arrastrase a toda la comunidad...

Comment: Nada más antiguo y rígido que el lenguaje máquina y míralo, ahí sigue xD Un lenguaje puede llegar a ser muy flexible, como Java o .NET (incluso V8 es sorprendentemente rápido con la máxima flexibilidad de Javascript), pero todas se apoyan en C y C++, porque lo estático permite la máxima optimización. Tampoco sería viable escribir librerías como OpenGL, DirectX o motores SQL en lenguajes más flexibles.

Comment: Estaba dándole vueltas. Se sabe que Java es más eficiente que C++ en algunos casos. Esto se debe a que Java optimiza mejor ciertos algoritmos vía arquitectura paralela (Flynn). Sin embargo, los motores Java como granparte de sus librerías están desarrolladas en C (puro y duro) y ASM ¿Por qué no lo hacen en Java si es más eficiente y flexible? Porque la optimización tiene un límite y no podría optimizarse a sí mismo. Como un archivo comprimido. Por eso se pueden crear lenguajes fantásticos y eficientes incluso más que el lenguaje nativo, pero nunca serán mejores que C/C++ y un buen programador.

Comment: Ahi estoy **totalmente** de acuerdo. Charlas sobre el tema ha habido varias en el chat. Por mucho que *optimize* un lenguaje,siempre habra casos concretos, en los que cambiar el algoritmo da un mejor resultado. Y la flexibilidad que te ofrecen C/C++ para eso es *ilimitada*. A costa, claro, de mucho café, pizza, y pocas horas de sueño xD