# ¿Cómo definir una función friend en una clase template?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto en c++ y he organizado el código en archivos .cpp y .hpp, pero al momento de compilar me sale un error en el que básicamente me dice que la referencia al operator<< es indefinida a pesar de que la he definido en su correspondiente archivo .cpp y su declaración en el archivo .hpp como se muestra a continuación:

Declaración en archivo .hpp

```
template<typename T>
class MiClase{
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MiClase &ob);
    T dato_;
public:
    MiClase(const T &dato);
};
```

Definicón en archivo .cpp

```
template<typename T>
MiClase<T>::MiClase(const T &dato)
    : dato_{ dato }
{}

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MiClase<T> &ob){
    return out<<ob.dato_;
}
```

Ya sé que es posible quitarme este error (porque ya lo intente) definiendo la función dentro de la declaración en el archivo .hpp tal que así:

```
template<typename T>
class MiClase{
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const MiClase &ob){
        return out<<ob.dato_;
    }
    T dato_;
public:
    MiClase(const T &dato){
        dato_ = dato;
    }
};
```

Pero estoy intentando de no romper el modo de organizar los archivos que llevo haciendo hasta ahora, ¿será que hay alguna manera de hacerlo como yo pretendo o no hay otra forma?.

Dejo imagen del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: También recuerda que las plantillas no puedes estar divididas en .h y .cpp. https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47912/169744

Comment: pero no es como que c++ prohiba separar plantillas en .h y .cpp, lo que pasa es que al separarlas, hay que tener en cuenta que ya no se puede hacer el include del archivo .h sino que se tiene que hacer el include del .cpp, haciendo esto se puede crear y luego usar las instancias de la clase plantilla. post data: la respuesta a la otra pregunta si me sirvio thanks!

Comment: El compilador necesita que las plantillas estén completas para generar las especializaciones. ¿Es posible separar la plantilla en 2 archivos o más? Si, pero haciendo trampa.